# Stereo speakers ~$100 (max $150)

Tags: audio, speakers

I'm looking for new 2.0 speakers (actually I'm using Creative T40 Series I).

Why change ? - My actual speakers are 7-8 years old and I think that they are not playing so good like at the begining, so I want to change them for new one.

Criteria:

- active speakers
- stereo, two speaker system
- price: ~100$ (maximum $150 but it has to be explained why it is better choice than ~$100 speakers)
- usage: gaming, listening pop/rock music
- important features: clear sound, hearable bass, volume control on speaker

What am I looking for ? -
I'm looking for speakers with the best sound quality in this price range.

**My ideas and other recommendations:**

Around $100:

- [Edifier R1600TIII](http://www.edifier.com/int/en/speakers/r1600-t3-2.0-powered-bookshelf) - $105
- [Microlab Solo 6C New](http://www.microlab.com/?r=Stereosystemen&st=full&id=658) - $115
- [Logitech Z150](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2660/1366) - $23 - recommended by Journeyman Geek (but I think it's not what I'm looking for)

Up to $150:

- [Edifier R1700BT](http://www.edifier.com/int/en/speakers/r1700bt-bluetooth-bookshelf) - $125
- [Microlab Solo 7C New](http://www.microlab.com/?r=Stereosystemen&st=full&id=659) - $152
- [M-Audio AV42](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2659/1366) - $148 - recommended by Journeyman Geek (AV-40 not available in my country)

Looking for advice if I can find anything better in this price range.

Comment: What is the problem with the ones you are thinking about? What other criteria do you have for the speakers you wish to purchase?

Comment: What sort of music will you listen to, how important is getting loud, and do you have any preference on active vs passive speakers?

Comment: @Andy What additional requirements should I add to reopen this question ?

Comment: The focus on this question should be about **experience with bookshelf** (bigger than typical PC stereo speakers) or **studio monitor stereo speakers** comparable to the Edifier model. Some models have features like Bluetooth, remotes and so forth. [Here is a narrowed down selection for Poland.](http://cenowarka.pl/?cat=spk&bpmax=240-650&v=e&hloc=pl&filter=aktualizuj&sort=p&xf=1203_2.0~2260_Sonstige~2260_Edifier~2260_Hercules~2260_M-Audio~2260_Microlab#xf_top) How you use them (music listening, gaming or music production) shouldn't matter much (objective sound). How to further improve? @Undo

Comment: @LiveWireBT There are [6 products](http://cenowarka.pl/?cat=spk&xf=1203_2.0~2260_Sonstige~2260_Edifier~2260_Hercules~2260_M-Audio~2260_Microlab&asuch=&bpmax=380-432&v=e&hloc=pl&plz=&dist=&filter=aktualizuj&mail=&sort=p) close to $100 in your comparison. How should I understand it ? That there is no difference in which I will choose ? All will sound similary ?

Comment: @ivaan no it's just a narrowed down selection to show that it's not to broad to answer your question and give a recommendation (I think most users just saw that the question is about "stereo pc speakers" without reading it carefully).

Comment: Additionally http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-computer-speakers/ is a nice starting point. I want to recommend the AV40s cause *I wanted them*, but I'm holding out for reviews on the AV42

Comment: Popping this here for references on bookshelf speakers http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-bookshelf-speakers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually tend to review hardware I have in these answers. I'll make an exception, and review hardware I'm *looking* at seriously, and a bit of quick audio teachery.

If I had these requirements, I'd look at the [AV40](http://www.m-audio.com/products/view/studiophile-av-40) (which alas, I could not get my paws on) or the [AV42](http://www.m-audio.com/products/view/av42) (Which is on my wishlist), both by M-Audio.

[image]

The AV40 has a *reputation*. [Wirecutter](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-computer-speakers/) considers it the best PC speaker you can buy. It has an aux in, a headphone out. Its powered (the left speaker has all the active things in it) and has a volume knob. It's even supposed to have little lights that tell you the speakers are angled correctly. Its also out of production.

I'm waiting on wirecutter to look at the AV42, but reviews are [decent](http://www.audiorumble.com/m-audio-av42-professional-studio-monitor-review/). Its not going to be a bass monster (get a proper sub for that), but its still going to be a decent pair of speakers. Monitors are designed for fairly flat response anyway.

I suggest this over the AV32 since its got a bigger woofer(and as such better bass). Its arguably prettier than its elder sibling.

[image]

Both models are under 150 USD.

Comment: Firstly thank you for answer but it's really hard to find comparision of this speakers with Edifiers and Microlabs. I'm not sure which choice will be better from speakers presented by me after edit and this presented by you. Additionally in review on Wirecutter we can't see any models from my list...

Comment: Wirecutter's the closest thing to a cross comparison I can find, and their methodology is pretty solid. They also have a seperate page for bookshelf speakers. I consider them a great *starting* point, but yes, they're by no means definitive. I also like these for the *overall* feature set, and since they're a good example of how stuff matter (want more bass? A larger speaker cone size might help)

Comment: More bass is not my goal I just want to choose solid speakers in this price range and I think that all options Edifiers, M-Audios, Microlabs will have enough bass for me. I put speakers from Edifier and Microlab in comparission because they are popular choices in this price range on forums in my country. Your proposition is really nice but I can't find any opinion if it's better than mine. I really would go with cheaper Edifiers R1600TIII or Microlabs 6C but if your choice is much better I could buy M-Audios but I can't find any proof that they are significantly better choice.

Comment: Sound is subjective in many cases. I'm suggesting criteria that helps in selection unless you can audition them and things to look for.

Comment: True but I really don't know how to narrow my criteria because I didn't listen to many "good" speakers and I couldn't form my own opinion about them. In this case I will probably go with cheapest Edifiers R1600TIII. If nothing new shows up in this question I will mark your answer because it brought most interesting proposition.

Answer (score 5):

While its a little below the pricerange, and the bass isn't *spectacular* I'd suggest taking a look at logitech's [z150](http://www.logitech.com/en-sg/product/multimedia-speakers-z150). They're fairly cheap, compact speakers. They arn't super bassy (I consider them to be *barely* passing the Indica test (I listen to how the start of the indica track Valokeilojen Vampyyri - where a VW van starts up)  for bass, though they're reasonable for everything else.  I replaced a larger pair of altec lansings that are the nokia 3110s of the speaker world with these and they've been acquitting themselves very well. Unlike the M Audios, they're easily available at the average computer store and if someone said "Hey, I need a pair of speakers" - this is very likely what I'd point them at.

They're clear (enough), and don't really clip at the levels I use them at. They have the same option of front headphone and aux ports as the speakers I'd rather have (the AV40/42 in my other answer), and very practical, compact general use speakers. The AV40s are a muscle car. This is a little [kei car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kei_car) that'll do well enough.

These may not be the speakers you end up with, or drool at, but these speakers will handle most things, with aplomb for not much money.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for Audioengine's A2+. They are extremely versatile desktop speakers with a 2.0 powered system that produces excellent quality audio, even without a subwoofer. You’ll pay between $200 and $300 for the A2+, which is definitely a bargain for top-end speakers. Full review - http://soundgenetics.com/best-computer-speakers/

Full disclosure: I am the author of the linked blog post.

Comment: If you link to products or websites that you're affiliated with, you [must disclose that affiliation](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) - not doing so can lead to your answer or account being deleted as spam.